# Where is my associative array and how do I access it using Perl DBI?

Tags: perl, syntax, dbi

I'm working with perl, and using DBI. Up to now, I've been using ->fetchall_arrayref to get the results of a database query, and just accessing the array by numeric keys. However, I much prefer to be able to access records by the field names (associative fetch) than numeric.

How do I do this, and what is the correct syntax for accessing the keys?

I would prefer something like:

```
$data[0]['name']
```

Instead of:

```
$data[0][1]
```

---

Working Solution

```
my %data;
@{$data{$id}}{('name')} = 'something';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `fetchall_hashref()` then you get the hash you are looking for.  The keys will be the field names from the database.  I am a little late, and Joe got it, but it will be.

```
$data->{0}->{'field'};
```

Comment: Thanks for the good example. The manual info I read makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @Ben When you strip away the noise, this answer boils down to stating the same information as @Joe did (without a link to the documentation) and the single line of code `$data->{0}->{'field'}` which remains unexplained and therefore is a **bad** example. For example, what is **`0`**? I know what it is, but do you? Since you seem to be averse to reading the documentation, I am going to go out on a limb and hypothesize that you don't.

Comment: @Sinan you might want to go a little easy on Ben, he said he looked at the documentation but couldn't make sense of it.  I was just taking his line of code which was php style and fixing it to perl style.  I figured since he had 0 he knew the context.  I'm sorry if it doesn't live up to your expectations.

Comment: You can simplify your answer quite a bit: `$data->{0}{field};`.  This works because the second arrow is not necessary, the after the first `[]` or `{}`, the dereference is implicit. Also, hash keys are quoted when they are single words.

Answer (score 5):

Read the [DBI docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI).  Particularly, [`fetchall_hashref`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#fetchall_hashref).

And you should also learn Perl syntax, as it's not the same as PHP.

Comment: I was looking for specific help please and thanks, not a RTFM answer. I took a look, but wasn't making a lot of sense. I know perl != PHP

Comment: If the size of the result set is not known, it would be safer to use `fetchrow_hashref` in a `while` loop. Further, assuming one wisely avoids using `SELECT * FROM` and limits the query to columns of interest only, it would be more efficient to use `fetchrow_arrayref` and assign to a small number of local variables.

Comment: The DBI documentation is huge, but it really is beneficial to at least skim over it, so you're aware of what functionality exists.

Comment: @Sinan -- you're right, fetchall_* isn't the best way to go for large datasets ... I made a (possibly bad) assumption that if he was using fetchall_arrayref that fetchall_hashref was the change he was looking for (and would meet his requested structure).

Comment: Your answer was correct and to the point in the context of the original question. I was just providing some complementary information.

Answer (score 5):

You can use selectall_arrayref for this. Here's example from the DBI manpage:

> You may often want to fetch an array of rows where each row is stored as a hash.
>        That can be done simple using:

```
  my $emps = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
      "SELECT ename FROM emp ORDER BY ename",
      { Slice => {} }
  );
  foreach my $emp ( @$emps ) {
      print "Employee: $emp->{ename}\n";
  }
```